# Hide Artha Dictionary Icon from Notification Area in Classic Interface?

Tags: 11.04, notification-area, gnome

I'm using Artha Dictionary, and all I want to do is hide its icon from the notification area without loosing its functionality (i.e. Ctrl+W to bring up the meaning of selected word and show the same using NotifyOSD.). The only reason why I want to do it is, Artha's icon is not monochrome and hence doesn't integrate well with rest of the icons showing in the panel.

[image: The Panel showing Artha's icon and other icons.]

While using Unity, the icon is not shown and I still get proper notifications of word meanings I look up, the icon appears on panel in the classic mode. Removing Notification Area from the panel also removes Artha's functionality. If icon cannot be hidden, I'll prefer to have a monochrome icon for Artha that looks perfect on panel.

Comment: The latest version of Artha 1.0.3 has the option of hiding the status bar/system tray icon. You can install it via the PPA http://launchpad.net/~legends2k/+archive/artha :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open usr/share/pixmaps/artha.png in an image editor.
2. a) To make it dissapear:  Resize the icon to 1 pixel in width and paint it transparent.

   b) To change the icon:  Paste any image you want over the top of the existing image.
3. Save the image to the Desktop.
4. Open Accessories;Terminal and enter the following command replacing zach with your own home folders name:

sudo mv '/home/zach/Desktop/artha.png' '/usr/share/pixmaps'

The changes should take effect upon restarting your computer.

Answer (score 0):

> While using Unity, the icon is not
>   shown and I still get proper
>   notifications of word meanings I look
>   up, the icon appears on panel in the
>   classic mode.

To enable this, I suggest that you do the following:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Type Alt-F2 and enter "dconf-editor"

Navigate to:

**(Ubuntu 11.04)** desktop -> unity -> panel

**(Ubuntu 12.10)** com -> canonical -> unity -> panel

Add 'artha' to the systray-whitelist, thus:

```
['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Mumble', 'Wine', 'Skype', 'hp-systray', 'scp-dbus-service', 'artha']
```

...and save it.

The artha icon should now appear on the "panel" or "notification area" (completely close Artha and re-open it).

Comment: I guess adding to white-list will make it appear, and I DON'T want it to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did.

Go to `/usr/share/pixmaps`.

Rename 'artha.png' to 'artha1.png'

Now you get this on start:

```
WARNING : Error loading icon file!
/usr/share/pixmaps/artha.png not found!
```

If you lose the icon in the menu after doing this:

Go to `/usr/share/applications`  and change the icon manually for Artha to `/usr/share/pixmaps/artha1.png` (usually with right click- Properties).

I hope in the next update a feature to hide tray icon is included. (Currently v1.0.2.)